# Android switching between activities

Tags: android

I currently have an activity called RaceActivity in my app which performs a setContentView() to display a surface view. 
Inside of my surface view I am checking to see if the user has won my game and when he/she has I would like to switch to another view that shows a simple game finished message. I have tried using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();         
intent.setClass(getContext(), RaceActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("code", 3);
((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

But this doesn't work for me. It shows the new view for a second then the screen goes black and it continues to execute the code on the previous surface view (I have a log statement so that I can see what it's doing).

How do I switch to the finish view and make it stop the previous view?

Comment: What do you mean by 'shows the new view for a second then the screen goes black'? Did you have something in your second activity that calls 'finish()' method? Once a new activity is shown, it should stay shown unless user closes it, or you programmatically closes it by 'finish'. It may also closes if you have an exception  in the new activity's onCreate or onResume methods.

Comment: I don't have a finish() or an exception it just goes all black while the previous surface view continues to print messages to the screen

Answer (score 0):

To start another activity and STAY in that activty, you want to use startActivity (Intent intent)

Try this instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent();         
intent.setClass(getContext(), RaceActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("code", 3);
((Activity)getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It still continues the code in the previous surface view which eventually causes the app to crash

Comment: you could just call finish() after startActivity.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,newclassname.class);
            intent.putExtra("code", 3);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: I can't do it like that, I'm calling those functions inside of the surface view and Intent does not take that as its first parameter

Comment: in ur surface view define context like this Context c; and than do as follow      Intent intent=new Intent(c.getContext(),newclassname.class);
            intent.putExtra("code", 3);
            c.startActivity();

Comment: that's basically what I did above